# Insert function output in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have such a piece of html code (Jade notation)

```
tr(ng-repeat="item in  List"): td
                            b {{item.Id}}
                            td {{item.TypeId}}
                            td {{item.UserId}}
```

and I need instead of item.TypeId to show result of someFunction(item.TypeId). 
How I denote that in the code?

Comment: Is someFunction a function that belongs to the controller, say $scope.someFunction(var1){...}?

Comment: Yes, can be from scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the function in the same way you would add any other value:

```
{{someFunction(item.Id)}}
```